# LLVM StructType isPacked()

Tags: llvm

I have problem calling LLVM StructType isPacked() function.  We are using llvm 3.9.

```
Under gdb:
(gdb) p *pt
$3 = {
  <llvm::CompositeType> = {
    <llvm::Type> = {
      Context = @0x7fffffffb210, 
      ID = llvm::Type::StructTyID, 
      SubclassData = 9, 
      NumContainedTys = 3, 
      ContainedTys = 0x472fed0
    }, <No data fields>}, 
  members of llvm::StructType: 
  SymbolTableEntry = 0x4731110
}
But 
(gdb) p pt->isPacked()
$5 = false
```

The packed struct is just a plain packed struct with typedef:

```
typedef struct aprgb {
      unsigned char R;
      unsigned char G;
      unsigned char B;
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) RGB_t ;
   ...
   void sum(RGB_t *in. ....)
   ...
```

I could not figure out why the isPacked is returning false.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your struct should be packed at IR level. After all, all the members are i8's and no padding, etc. is required (on major architectures). Note that the source-level attributes are not directly translated to IR features. Instead, the frontend models whatever semantics the source language has using the semantics of LLVM IR.

Per LLVM Language reference (https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#t-struct):

> Structures may optionally be “packed” structures, which indicate that the alignment of the struct is one byte, and that there is no padding between the elements. In non-packed structs, padding between field types is inserted as defined by the DataLayout string in the module, which is required to match what the underlying code generator expects.